# Installing Ubuntu: root failed on restart

Tags: ubuntu, boot, installation

I just installed Ubuntu. At the end, it tells me to keep away the CD and to restart.
After I restart it tells me:

```
searching for boot record form ide-0..not found
searching for boot record form cdrom..not found
root failure
press any key to continue
reboot or select proper boot device.
```

I have just one CD-ROM and one IDE hard drive.

Comment: is this a bios error message?  or is it coming from Grub or Ubuntu?  it looks like you're not even getting to a Grub boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a BIOS error - there's no sign of an Ubuntu install.

What version of Ubuntu did you install (remembering that 10.04 is still in beta and that you shouldn't be installing it if you don't know what you're doing).